# Conflito com Controle de Versão GIT/Github para mesmo branch e apenas um usuário commitando

Tags: git, github

Sou harduser e programador experiente, porém um problema vem ocorrendo: **para um repositório privado no Github, com apenas um usuário commitando, eventualmente ao enviar código recebo aviso de que foi negado**, e que preciso dar pull antes. Quando isso é feito, o git alerta erros extremamente estúpidos, e ao "resolver", a interface do github exibe o seguinte:

```
Merge branch 'master' of github.com:fititnt/repositorio
Conflicts:
    pasta/pasta2/arquivo.js

master
fititnt authored 11 minutes ago
Showing 0 changed files with 0 additions and 0 deletions.
```

## Pontos pertinentes

- Apenas um usuário, de apenas um computador (Ubuntu 12.04), usando linha de comando e `git gui` e `gitk`
- Aparentemente, não há mudança de permissões de arquivos quando esse erro ocorre
- Jamais uso `--force`, `git rebase` e `git commit --amend`.
- git version 1.7.9.5
- O erro não acontece *sempre*. Costuma ocorrer quando estou várias horas fora do computador.

## Solução de contorno temporária

Solução de contorno que uso quando isso ocorre é salvar todas as alterações *fora* do git, usar o comando `git reset --hard HEAD~1` que efetivamente destroi qualquer referencia ao commit que foi feito localmente, dou pull, reaplico as alterações e então commito com sucesso e sem erro. Porém isso é irritante fazer pelo menos uma vez a cada um ou dois dias.

Estou desconfiado que isso pode ser um erro do Github ou bug do git.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em vez de dar `git pull`, faça um `git fetch`, e então `git log origin/branch` e `git log branch` para comparar o local com o remoto, e descobrir o que, exatamente, tem no remoto que não tem no local, para descobrir o que está acontecendo.

Assumo que você não faz `git rebase` ou `git commit --amend`? Uso desses comandos após um push vai fazer os repositórios divergirem, causando problemas desse tipo (solução: nunca faça rebase ou amend depois de push, ou, se fizer, use --force no push).

Comment: Alterei a pergunta para explicitar que nem o `git rebase` ou `git commit --amend` são usados. Vou ter que esperar o erro se repetir para testar o `git fetch` -> `git log origin/branch` -> `git log branch`.